# unexpected token error .then | promises | nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, unexpected-token

I've been working on the routing file below. However, it's essentially a photo app where I'll be able to store the data in MondoDB. However, when I run the code below, terminal keeps saying unexpected token .then. Am I missing something here?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'public/images/'});
var Photo = require ('../models/travelModels');

router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    Photo.find({})
      .then((photos) =>{
       res.render('lists', {
       list: photos
     });
  });
});

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next)=>{

   var path = "/static/images" + req.file.filename;
   var item  = {
      destination: req.body.destination,
      description: req.body.description,
      imageurl: path,
      mimetype: req.file.mimetype,
      filename: req.file.filename
    }

  // save photo in database
    var entry = new Photo (item);
    entry.save();
       .then(()=>{
        res.redirect('/mylist')
      });
    // or catch error
       .catch((err)=>{
          if (err){
            console.log(err);
         }
      });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: nvm i think i figured out it! extra semicolon was making terminal scream :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the semicolons, before the `then` and before the `catch`

```js
var entry = new Photo (item);
entry.save()
 .then(()=>{
  res.redirect('/mylist')
 })
 .catch((err)=>{
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
 });
```